# scroll table view on selecting a textfield

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitableview

i have a tableview with a text field on each cell the problem is tableview should scroll up on selecting the text field.here i'm attaching my project can u please let me know what mistake i had made.

here is the link u can download it from here http://pastelink.me/dl/9c2f89

code that i have used to scroll up.

```
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
UITableViewCell *cellC = (UITableViewCell *)[[textField superview]superview];
[tabController scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[tabController indexPathForCell:cellC] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: is the tabcontrller ur tableview refference?or is a tableview controller itself?did u tried [tableview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];if u r using  a tableview seperately.

Comment: please use Custom cell on tableView.

Comment: it is tableviewcontroller

Comment: can u download the project and check

Comment: In this case I would like to use `UIScrollView`. And will set its `contentOffset:` according to `textFields`.

Comment: cant we scroll this up like this

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:n inSection:0];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                    atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                            animated:YES];can u try this.i dont understand why u r calling it in willappear?

Comment: check ur contentview size.and ensure that it is more than the screen height...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this project [here](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) 
add this class to your project and try to use it it may work(TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView .h/TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView .m).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the code,

```
[tabController scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[tabController indexPathForCell:cellC] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

allow the tableView to scroll only when the content size is greater than the view height..

The above code will works if you give higher row count For eg: 15

Comment: yes, if you increase the row count or section count it is working

Answer (score 0):

Give tag to ur text filed properly in `cellForRowAt:`

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[textField convertPoint:textField.frame.origin toView:self.tableView]];
```

when the textField becomes active, use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`

for scroll the tableview